Input filter vs damping resistor
I have a buck regulator with a switching frequency around 200kHz with a π filter (4.7µF capacitor and a 33µH inductor) to attenuate the switching frequency back the main supply.
In this TI input filter documentation, we can see the possibility to add a resistor in parallel with the inductor to damp the inductor resonance: https://www.ti.com/lit/an/snva538/snva538.pdf
What is the impact of this resistor in the EMC point of view?
In the case of conducted emission test, is this resistor will "shunt" the filtering effect of the inductor?

Same question about Immunity to conducted disturbances test (61000-4-6), is this resistor will "shunt" the filtering effect of the inductor? Im worried about that because at 30MHz, the impedance of a SMD resistor is similar to the resistance value (negligible effect of the parasitic capacitance and inductance). If I have a 5Ω resistance in parallel of the 33µH inductor (MPN : 744045330) which had a 6kΩ impedance, will I have 5Ω impedance (5Ω // 6kΩ ≈ 5Ω) and an inefficient input filter?

Thanks

Why not simulate the filter and get all the results you could possibly want. Then, if you still have doubts, come back and ask a question.

You're right, but as I explained to Tim, I'm not familiar with some of the concepts of regulator sizing and simulation.
Do you have any recommendations for simulation tools?
Thanks

An inductor by itself will have a high Q. At some resonance frequency, the attenuation of the filter will be mostly defeated, and lead to a high EMC output or sensitivity.
Shunting the inductor with a resistor will indeed reduce the filter attenuation at some frequencies, but it will also improve the filter radically at the resonance.
It needs careful measurement, and knowledge of the spectrum of EMI being produced, to size the resistor, or choose the inductor type, to get an overall filter attenuation that meets the EMC requirements. Experience of one type of equipment may not be a good guide to what you should do with a different design. As you say, the paper talks about the 'possibility' of adding a damping resistor. I'm a great fan of using a ferrite bead where possible as the inductor in such filter, most grades provide the damping as loss in the ferrite.

When hit with an impulse, LC circuits will ring at a frequency determined by the inductance and surrounding capacitors.
On a switching power supply input, there are current pulses where the edges act as impulses. This ringing will generally be at lower frequencies (perhaps below 1 MHz) where the Q of the inductor is high, even for lossy ferrite beads.
By placing a resistor across the inductor, it will lower the Q of the LC circuit and prevent ringing. Placing the resistor across the inductor is generally safe since most of the DC current flows through the inductor, not the resistor, i.e., minimal dissipation in the resistor. In my experience, a value of resistance in the 10 to 100 ohm range has been helpful.

The resistor reduces Q of the circuit, which helps reduce resonance (having a high gain peak), but worsens high-frequency attenuation (at high frequencies, L becomes an open circuit, R dominates, and you get a CRC filter).
In technical terms, the resistor introduces a zero to the transfer function.
That is, when we express the transfer function H = Vout/Vin as a function of frequency, constructed from ideal "lumped element" R, L and C, we find a rational polynomial equation, of which the numerator (zeroes) and denominator (poles) can be factored into roots (real roots or complex pairs as the case may be).
When a zero lies near or between poles, it acts to cancel out their effect: poles give the asymptotic attenuation at high frequencies that we desire from a low-pass filter, and zeroes act to cancel that out.  Sometimes this is done strategically (position a zero near a specific harmonic to improve attenuation there, to compromise with overall performance), other times it's unfortunate (like here), or accidental (the stray properties of real components manifest as higher-frequency poles and zeroes).
The effect on peak and asymptote are easily demonstrated in simulation; I will leave this as exercise for the reader.  (We even have a handy schematic entry and simulation tool here: everything can be done from the comfort of the edit box.)

Although I studied many years ago, I'm not familiar with the notions of poles and zeros due to a lack of practice and the very mathematical complexity with which this subject is brought up.
I think I need to try and simulate this part.
Can you recommend any simulation tools? Also if you have any books or documents dealing with good power supply sizing (filtering, compensation, capacitance and inductance sizing, etc.), I'd love to hear from you.
Thank you
